# how to change the komodo line ending character

Tags: komodo

I wrote a python program in Windows env, but it needs to be display and run in Linux env. I realize every line has a ending of \r. I did go into edit -> current file setting-> line ending, and change the option to 'Unix(\n)'. However, I am still seening the same issue, and \r is still there.
Anyone know why?

Answer (score 3):

Once you've changed the line endings in your preferences you need to "Clean" the lines endings; Code > Clean Line Endings.